# How to get the selected value of star rating on submit form

Tags: ajax, select

I'd like to get the selected value of this ajax star rating, I don't know why, but
 it's no so obvious that it's mean.

```
<span id="stars-cap"></span>
    <div id="stars-wrapper2">
     <select name="selrate">
         <option value="1">Déplorable</option>
         <option value="2">Pas satisfaisant</option>
         <option value="3">Correct</option>
         <option value="4" selected="selected">Très satisfaisant</option>
         <option value="5">Parfait</option>
</select>
```

I have 4 blocks After rating, the user must submit a form.

I try to add this :

```
document.getElementById('selrate').value
```

with id like this :

but it don't run...

You can see the exemple here : http://www.developper-photo.com/tpl/avis-labos.php

Thank for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
var selectedOption = ​$('select[name=selrate] option:selected').text()​;
```

Try the above script and pass this `selectedOption` to your ajax request parameter.
I believe you are familiar with `jquery` and my script may work only with including `jquery` in your website.

Comment: No it's doesn't run ...  you can see i have done the modification you explain but it don't run ??